# modified KnapSack runtime error

Tags: c++, runtime-error, knapsack-problem

I am facing a problem in solving a program on codechef which is a modified version of knapsack problem ..
1.here i have to find maximum cost for all possible weight..1<=n<=W
2.i have solved it using standard DP algo...but each time i submit my code ..i get a runtime error...
Please have a look at my code ..

```
   #include<bits/stdc++.h>
   using namespace std;
   #define  ll long long
   ll _max(ll a,ll b){return a>b?a:b;}
   ll sol[200009];
   void knapsack(ll W,ll val[],ll wt[],ll n,ll sol[])
   {
      ll i,w;
      ll K[n+1][W+1];


         for(ll i=0;i<=n;i++)
         {
              for(ll w=0;w<=W;w++)
              {
                if(i==0 || w==0)
                K[i][w]=0;
                else
                {
                   if(wt[i-1]<=w)
                   K[i][w]=max(val[i-1]+K[i-1][w-wt[i-1]],K[i-1][w]);
                   else
                   K[i][w]=K[i-1][w];
                }
              }
         }
         for(int j=0;j<W;j++)
         {
             sol[j]=K[n][j+1];
             printf("%lld ",sol[j]);
         }

    }

    int main()
    {
        ll n;
        scanf("%lld",&n);
        ll val[n];
        ll wt[n];

        ll sum =0;
        for(ll i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
           scanf("%lld",&wt[i]);
           scanf("%lld",&val[i]);
           sum+=wt[i];
        }

        knapsack(sum, val, wt, n,sol);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Do you know the text or number of this error?

Comment: It is a good time to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: can you tell the question on codechef??

Comment: http://www.codechef.com/COOK47/problems/KNPSK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i don't guarantee this will give you an AC

You overlooked the constraints while coding your solution

```
3 ≤ N ≤ 100000;

1 ≤ W ≤ 2, for each item;

1 ≤ C ≤ 109, for each item.
```

Your matrix

```
long long  K[n+1][W+1];
```

will not be allocated because the highest value of n is 100000 and

W = sum = weight[i] * n which can be as high as 2*100000

which is equivalent to allocating  K[100000][200000] which will give Runtime error